# Spilled denat. alcohol (5% methanol)

Tags: home-experiment, safety

I spilled a small amount of denatured alcohol (~3ml) on my skin and table while prepping microscope slides for springtails. The bottle says its 95% ethanol, with unspecified amounts of isopropanol and methanol. Wiped it up immediately with a paper towel, washed my hands with soap and water, scrubbed the table with water and wiped it down again. I'm a little bit worried, first about skin contact, and second about fumes. I had been using the denatured alcohol in small amounts for about an hour previously while preparing slides (small drops pipetted onto glass). I didn't realize it had methanol until after the fact, if I had known I would not have used it or at the very least been more careful (and perhaps not leaned over the microscope with my nose uncomfortably close to the slide...)

I called poison control and they said it *should* be fine but the MSDS indicates you should seek immediate medical attention so I'm not sure.

Comment: The dose makes the poison and your dose was very small.

Comment: I wonder what the poison control center is good for. Your behavior was unnecessary - or perhaps necessary due to lack of knowledge -  and they *should* know that.

Comment: Did you compiled the MSDS of the chemicals to be used *before* working with the chemicals in question?  Did you asked your colleague/supervisor *ahead* of time about the chemicals to learn about the *potential* hazard and to set this into context (quantity of the chemicals, possible pathways of intoxication [skin, inhalation, ...] and how to limit the exposure)? When in doubt, ask and get familiar *ahead* of time.

Comment: the *antidote* to methanol is ethanol. And the risk from methanol in this mixture would be very small anyway unless you drank it.

Answer (score 3):

According to [researchgate.net  Legal-limits-for-methanol-contents](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Legal-limits-for-methanol-contents-in-grams-per-liter-of-100-vol-alcohol-in-different_tbl2_346965478)(fast search, not pretending to be an authoritative source), alcoholic drinks have the methanol content limit 7 g / L of 100% ethanol ( US/AU/NZ). For EU it is 2-13.5 g/L of 100% ethanol, depending on the drink class.

IF we take the US value 7 g/L, it is close to 1% of methanol in ethanol.

Fear of having skin contaminated by 3 mL of 5% methanol is not justified. It could have methanol content equivalent roughly to some 40 mL of low quality 40% spirit and you have not even drunk it.

Remember the quote "The dose makes the poison.". Your dose was very small.

Note that ethanol denaturation additives are unbearable or dangerous at intentional drinking of such ethanol, but safe at accidental skin contamination.

Comment: The table is form http://dx.doi.org/10.3390/pr8121609, which seems to be a peer-reviewed journal. So while researchgate in itself might not be an authoritative source, the journal is likely to be that. Also, honey spirits do not have a limit in the EU. Also: [Why is Denaturated alcohol made poisonous?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/158469/4945)