Ethanol Interactions
I would like to know if anyone is aware of any substance which, when it interactives with alcohol (ethanol), and is consumed, changes the taste of the alcohol (negatively) and/or induces sickness in the person who consumes the alcohol.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/158469/why-is-denaturated-alcohol-made-poisonous/158470

"interactivate" is probably not  the word you were looking for. How about simply "when mixed with"?

Altering the flavor of alcohol is the basis for much of the alcoholic beverage industry. And there is a long list of compounds soluble in alcohol that arguably taste bad. That makes this a somewhat broad question. Can you be more clear or specific about the purpose of this to narrow down the choices?

You mean denatured alcohol?

Not sure if this applies to your particular question, but there is a drug which causes illness (fairly often violent vomitting) when combined with alcohol. Antabuse (disulfiram) was frequently prescribed for the treatment of alcoholism in the last century. For the individual who has taken the drug, even a small amount of alcohol results in the unpleasant symptoms frequently associated with bad hangovers.
Ethanol is normally metabolized to acetic acid. While more mechanisms of action have been found, at the time it was thought that the drug's inhibition of ethanol metabolism by aldehyde dehydrogenase inhibition, causing the accumulation of acetaldehyde in the blood, caused the symptoms. The drug has since been found to have an effect on a number of other metabolic pathways as well.
Though very effective as a deterrent to alcohol intake, there is the problem of poor compliance. That and newer treatments has decreased the prescribing of disulfiram for alcohol abuse.

I believe you're referring to "Denaturation" of ethanol. This is done to prevent consumption of ethanol meant for industrial applications.
This can be done by mixing methanol with the ethanol; methanol is oxidised to methanoic acid in the body, which can cause blindness or even death.
Denaturation may also be done by mixing some amount of $\ce{CuSO4}$ (for a distinct colour), and pyridine (for the foul odour).
